# How to copy a file from a GCS bucket in Dataproc to HDFS using google cloud?

Tags: hadoop, google-cloud-dataproc

I had uploaded the data file to the GCS bucket of my project in Dataproc. Now I want to copy that file to HDFS. How can I do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## For a single "small" file

You can copy a single file from Google Cloud Storage (GCS) to HDFS using the `hdfs` copy command. Note that you need to run this from a node within the cluster:

```
hdfs dfs -cp gs://<bucket>/<object> <hdfs path>
```

This works because `hdfs://<master node>` is the default filesystem. You can explicitly specify the scheme and NameNode if desired:

```
hdfs dfs -cp gs://<bucket>/<object> hdfs://<master node>/<hdfs path>
```

Note that GCS objects use the `gs:` scheme. Paths should appear the same as they do when you use `gsutil`.

## For a "large" file or large directory of files

When you use `hdfs dfs`, data is piped through your local machine. If you have a large dataset to copy, you will likely want to do this in parallel on the cluster using DistCp:

```
hadoop distcp  gs://<bucket>/<directory> <HDFS target directory>
```

Consult the [DistCp documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-distcp/DistCp.html) for details.

## Consider leaving data on GCS

Finally, consider leaving your data on GCS. Because the GCS connector implements Hadoop's distributed filesystem interface, it can be used  as a drop-in replacement for HDFS in *most* cases. Notable exceptions are when you rely on (most) atomic file/directory operations or want to use a latency-sensitive application like [HBase](https://hbase.apache.org/). The [Dataproc HDFS migration guide](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/migration/hadoop/hadoop-gcp-migration-data) gives a good overview of data migration.